# Custom CellFactory for ListView

Tags: listview, javafx, javafx-8

I want to implement custom CellFactory for ListView:

```
  import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class MainApp extends Application
{
    ListView<String> list = new ListView<String>();
    ObservableList<String> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        "Option 1",
        "Option 2",
        "Option 3",
        "Option 4",
        "Option 5"
    );

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        VBox box = new VBox();
        Scene scene = new Scene(box, 200, 200);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("ListViewSample");
        box.getChildren().addAll(list);
        VBox.setVgrow(list, Priority.ALWAYS);

        list.setItems(data);

        list.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>()
        {
            @Override
            public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> list)
            {
                return new ColorRectCell();
            }
        }
        );

        stage.show();
    }

    class ColorRectCell extends ListCell<String>
    {
        public ColorRectCell()
        {
            addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
            {
                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent)
                {
                    if (mouseEvent.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY) && !isEmpty())
                    {
                        if (mouseEvent.getClickCount() == 2)
                        {
                            System.out.println(">>>>>>>>> Clicked");
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty)
        {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (item != null)
            {
                setText(item);

            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I want to activate the double click listener only if I click on a row with text and skip it if the row is empty. What is the proper way to implement the double click listener into the CellFactory?

Comment: what's wrong with registering the listener with the cell (vs. with the listView) - after all your questions you should have learned how to it, shouldn't you :-)

Comment: @kleopatra I can't find any good example how I can insert listener into the custom CellFactory.

Comment: ?? a cellfactory creates a Cell which is a Node which can have a handler/filter for ui events: either register it in the factory after creation or in the constructor of your custom cell

Comment: @kleopatra code updated. By the way can you propose some better code implementation?

Comment: repeating: _in the constructor_ of the custom cell

Comment: @kleopatra I updated the code. Now again I have click event in empty cell which is not correct.

Comment: hint: the cell has an _empty_ property ...

Comment: @kleopatra  yes but it's located under `updateItem`. Can you show some code sample? I don't understand how to refactor the code.

Comment: please read the api doc - and carefully re-read my hint: cell has an empty _property_ :-)

Comment: @kleopatra code updated. What about this proposal? Any other advice for improvement?

Comment: don't see any check for the _empty property_ ..

Comment: @kleopatra code is updated.